# How to do Game logics in OpenGL (GLUT) and C++?

Tags: opengl, logic, glut

I am programming the game Battleship in OpenGL(GLUT) and C++.

I know how do to the graphics stuff (like displaying the field and predefined ships),
but where should I put my game code like:

- if key left pressed select one field left and display it
- if a ship is placed then display the ship

Things like place a ship (switching between the fields) I can't do in the display() function, but if a ship is placed it must be drawn by the display() function, right?

I don't know where to put the game logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the basic, classic [**game loop**](http://www.koonsolo.com/news/dewitters-gameloop/). Effectively, your game runs in one giant loop. In this loop, you handle user input, react to the user input, run AI, and update the video/audio in response. This is, of course, a very simplified take on it, but it will suffice for Battleship.

Conceptually, more or less:

```
while(Game.IsRunning)
{
    Input = GetInput();
    Game.Update(Input);
    Display(Game);
}
```

If you're actually doing real-time as opposed to event-driven, then you need to make your updates take into account the time-passed since the last update, as well as player input. I'll keep this short and limited to what you're asking though.

Answer (score 1):

`GLUT` provides functions to intercept mouse keyboards events, like

```
void keyboardDown(unsigned char key, int x, int y);
void mouseClick(int button, int state, int x, int y);  
void mouseMotion(int x, int y);
```

You may reimplement those function to get a custom behavior of your program.

For example, if you want to draw a ship after the user pushes "s" then, in your `keyboardDown` function, you may set a global flag to 1. Then, in the display function, you may check that flag. If it's `1` then you'll draw your ship.

Of course it's up to you how to place/move your ship :)

For further informations, take a look at the [documentation](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/glut/spec3/spec3.html)

Answer (score 0):

you probably want to use keyboard function and save the key pressed on stack and compare on the display which keys where pressed by the player so you can get multiple key detection something like this:

```
// for pressed keys
void keybd(unsigned char key,int x, int y){
//int pe;
 switch(key){
  case 'w':up=true;break;
  case 's':down=true;break;
  case 'd':right=true;break;
  case 'a':left=true;break;
  case ' ':trig=true;break;
 }
}
// for released keys
void ms_r(unsigned char key,int x, int y){
//int pe;
 switch(key){
  case 'w':up=false;break;
  case 's':down=false;break;
  case 'd':right=false;break;
  case 'a':left=false;break;
 }
}
```

and then just compare which keys have true and act based on that
and when you are calling the glut main loop and functions
use:

```
glutIgnoreKeyRepeat(1);
glutKeyboardUpFunc(ms_r);
glutKeyboardFunc(keybd);
```